# Observing a field in rails and mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, observers

I have a `User` model and `Following`, `Follower`

**User Model**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :followers, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :following
has_and_belongs_to_many :following, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :followers
```

**Followers**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :followers, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :following
```

**Following**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :followings, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :followers
```

And I have a `UserObserver` which should see if user `follower_ids` go changed then add it to the user `Activities`

So how can I watch changes only in `follower_ids` and get the latest user `id` to put in the `activities`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best option, in this case, is to encapsulate the logic of adding new followers in a method, and, in this method, you can trigger whatever you want:

```
#encoding: utf-8
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :followers, type: Array
  attr_readonly :followers

  def add_new_follower(new_follower)
    unless followers.include?(user) 
      followers << user 
      trigger_added_follower_observers(user)
    end
  end

  private
  def trigger_added_follower_observers(new_follower)
    # trigger the stuff you want
  end
end
```

There are alternative options, like use ruby's Observable module (http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html), MongoID observers (http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/callbacks.html#observers), or before_save hook, however IMHO i think the above's code is the best option you have, without "hurting" your model.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it user observers? because triggers may work with this, but I want to have a class that handle user activities on their own, like having a new post not just new follower, and it would be bad code to have triggers going everywhere

Comment: You can just replace the #trigger_added_follower_observers method to #call_observer and change the signature of the method to receive an identifier (a symbol) to identify which part of your model has changed. Then, inside the method, you will instantiate your UserObserver passing self (the user) and the identity of what has changed (:followers, :posts, ...). I really dont think that the hooks or using observable module will be any better than that.